# Bootstrap Modal not show fullscreen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap Modal to quick popup my news.

Currently, I have the problem when clicking on link; it only shows a box. It's not fullscreen.

My question simple is: have any method to append `width` and `height` of the class contain `modal` to `body` to show fullscreen.

I think because of it a child of another parent. And it can't show fullscreen.

Have any method to show a class of div is fullscreen not dependency any parent element?

Struct my code like this:

```css
.contentfit {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.right-content {
    background-color: #5AA258;
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
  <div class="contentfit">
    <div class="right-content">
      <section id="hoicho">
        <div class="title">
          <h2>The title</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="services">
          <ul>
            <li>Services 1</li>
            <li>Services 2</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap">
          <div class="frameallcontent">
            <div class="containter">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  <p class="title-p"> <a href="javascript:void(0,0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tintuchoicho">Click to link</a>
                  </p>
                  <!-- Modal -->
                  <div class="modal fullscreen-modal fade" id="tintuchoicho" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          ...
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="left-content">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I only show a part of my code.

You can see in real my example look like this.

[image]

When I click the link underline, it only shows small popup like this.

Comment: could you provide a link to the page where actual problem can be seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this script at the bottom of your page, just before closing `</body>`.

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){
  $('.modal.fade').appendTo('body');
})
```

It will effectively move your modals from wherever they are placed, making them direct children of `<body>`.

If this doesn't work, it means you're overriding the default CSS of `.modal` and you will need to produce a minimal, complete and verifiable example of your problem here or using any online snippet tool.

Comment: It not working with me. You can see it show like that: http://i.imgur.com/bKHAp0x.png and in Chrome Dev Tools: http://i.imgur.com/5XMeC01.png

Comment: I can't inspect images, vanloc. Create a [mcve]. Are there any errors in your browser's `console`?

Comment: You need to bring from your environment whatever is making it display bad. If we can't inspect, we can't help. As you can see, in your question It is working correctly. There's nothing wrong with your markup. Can you bring all the CSS that applies to your page? That is most likely the problem.

Comment: Thanks, @AndreiGheorghiu. I understand my problem. Can be another CSS affect to the page. So, I need to find it before request a question.

Comment: Could you check if `#fullpage` has a `z-index` and make sure it's not higher than `1040`?

Comment: I not using `z-index` in this element.

Comment: What are you displaying in modal? Is it anything with a 3d CSS transform? In Chrome Dev Tools, if you select an element and press Delete you remove it from DOM. This way you can find out very fast what element is causing this. Than you reload and go to children of that element and so on. Or you give a link and I'll find it fast :) (I hope).

Comment: I only show data like text and image I added in the database. Yeah, not using any 3d CSS function like `transform`. Currently, I fixed manually with each screen resolution. It's a bad method but resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstraps documentation says:

> **Modal markup placement**
>   Always try to place a modal's HTML code in a
>   top-level position in your document to avoid other components
>   affecting the modal's appearance and/or functionality.

Taken from here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

So i would suggest moving it down the document to before the closing `</body>` tag if possible. that should resolve your problem.

Comment: This link should put at this position. Your mention I should move only `<div class="modal fullscreen-modal fade"` before the closing </body>? I tried to put this after at `<body>` and before `</body>`. But it not show anything.

Comment: You need to move the entire div and all of it's contents. If I were you I would remove "fullscreen-modal" from the "modal" class div and add "modal-lg" to the "modal-dialog" class div. eg: <div class="modal fade"><div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">